# How to store the subject of email being composed in a variable?

Tags: vba, outlook

When an email is being composed and information is written in the subject line.

After clicking outside the subject line, how can I take part(s) of the subject line and transfer to the body of the email.

For instance, a new email composed below:

> **Email Header** 
>   To: Joe Bloggs 
>   cc: 
>   Bcc:
>   Subject: NZD10000 REF:0000001 2018/08/18
>
> **Body**
>
> Reference Number:  **0000001**
>   Date:              **2018/08/18**
>
> Thanks.

```
Public MItem As MailItem
Public MySubject As String

Sub NewSecureMail()

    Set MItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    MySubject = MItem.Subject
    MsgBox (MySubject)

End Sub
```

The msgbox produces a blank result. If I can store the text contained in the subject line into a variable, I can then work with the variable.

Comment: It sounds more like the Subject information is from somewhere else, and needs to be put  both into the SubjectLine and into the Body.  (Or is the typist really keying that long string of alpha/numeric characters?)  Where is the original Subject info sourced?  Can we eliminate both typings?

Comment: Show us what you have tried? we need to see you have some code written by you first, most of the newcomers think this is a code-for-me-please website

Comment: I have attached what I have started so far. The msgbox produces a blank result. Essentially, if I can store the text contained in the subject line into a variable, I can then work with the variable.

Comment: Sounds like a LostFocus/AfterUpdate thing.  Did you put a breakpoint in and see what it thinks the value of MItem.Subject is at that point?  I'd think you'd want to put some code in the LostFocus or AfterUpdate event of the textbox where you types the Subject line.  Then, you can grab the value, parse out what you need and add it to the body all in one step.

Answer (score 0):

`.CreateItem` should give you hint you created a new blank mail. You do not see this unless you `.Display` so you might think you referenced the mail with the subject.

Instead use `Set MItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem`.